# Bash passed parent arguments to child script even though I did not use source before the child script call

Tags: bash, arguments, parent

I have an argument-resolving issue in a child script like `var=$@`; but the `$@` values are from parent script not the child's. I have found some posts which other person have similar issue but with the explicit `source child_script` in the parent script; that might be a reason `$@` was passed over.  But I did not put `.` or `source` before the child_script call in the parent_script.

Why is it treated as `source child_script` by Bash? Is there any setting to override?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Please [edit] it to include a complete set of code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening.

Comment: sorry for this. but it seems I am not able to give a minimal example as minimal example works fine but in the lengthy code the issue appears. I will delete this post soon since I explicitly use 'bash my_child_script'  seems solves this problem.